# Having trouble reading String from MySQL table to Eclipse

Tags: java, jdbc, enums, resultset

I have a project of coupons but I have an issue when trying to read a coupon to Eclipse. I have a table of categories which are connected to my coupons table in row "CATEGORY_ID" which is an int. when using add Method I convert my ENUM to int in order to add it to CATEGORY_ID with no problem.

my issue is when trying to read it, I try and convert it to STRING to get a text value, however, I get an exception.

*here is my code:*

**ENUM CLASS:**

```
public enum Category {

FOOD(1), ELECTRICITY(2), RESTAURANT(3), VACATION(4), HOTEL(5);

private Category(final int cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
}

private int cat;

public int getIDX() {
    return cat;
}

private Category(String cat1) {
    this.cat1 = cat1;
}

private String cat1;

public String getName() {
    return cat1;
}
}
```

**A Method to add coupon to table COUPONS:**

```
// sql = "INSERT INTO `couponsystem`.`coupons` (`COMPANY_ID`,`CATEGORY_ID`,`TITLE`, `DESCRIPTION`, 
          `START_DATE`, `END_DATE`, `AMOUNT`, `PRICE`, `IMAGE`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

@Override
    public void addCoupon(Coupon coupon) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();

    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(ADD_COUPON);
        statement.setInt(1, coupon.getCompanyID());
        statement.setInt(2, coupon.getCategory().getIDX());
        statement.setString(3, coupon.getTitle());
        statement.setString(4, coupon.getDescription());
        statement.setDate(5, (Date) coupon.getStartDate());
        statement.setDate(6, (Date) coupon.getEndDate());
        statement.setInt(7, coupon.getAmount());
        statement.setDouble(8, coupon.getPrice());
        statement.setString(9, coupon.getImage());
        statement.execute();

    } finally {
        pool.restoreConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

**Method to get coupon:**

```
// GET_ONE_COUPON = "SELECT * FROM `couponsystem`.`coupons` WHERE (`id` = ?);";


@Override
    public Coupon getOneCoupon(int couponID) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();

        Coupon result = null;
        
        List<Category> cats = new ArrayList<Category>(EnumSet.allOf(Category.class));
        

        try {

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_ONE_COUPON);
            statement.setInt(1, couponID);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
            result = new Coupon(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getInt(2), Category.valueOf(resultSet.getString(3)),
                    resultSet.getString(4), resultSet.getString(5), resultSet.getDate(6), resultSet.getDate(7),
                    resultSet.getInt(8), resultSet.getDouble(9), resultSet.getString(10));

        } finally {
            pool.restoreConnection(connection);
        }

        return result;
```

on column index (3) I try a and convert ENUM to string to get a text value, here is where I get an exception.

**EXCEPTION:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant coupon.beans.Category.5
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)
    at coupon.beans.Category.valueOf(Category.java:1)
    at coupon.dbdao.CouponsDBDAO.getOneCoupon(CouponsDBDAO.java:125)
    at coupon.Program.main(Program.java:65)
```

Hope I am clear with my question. I have no issue adding any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueOf` expects a string that corresponds to the name of the enum element, like "FOOD" but it looks like you pass a number. If you want to pass the id (number) from your enum you need a method to translate between the number and the enum element. Something like this

```
//in the enum Category
public static Category categoryFor(int id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      return FOOD;
      case 2: 
      return ELECTRICITY;
      //... more case
      default:
      return HOTEL;
  }
}
```

and then call it like

```
Category.categoryFor(resultSet.getInt(2))
```

or you need to store the actual name of the element in your table.

Also you shouldn't use *, "SELECT * ...", in your query but a list of column names so it is clear what column you map in your java code, "SELECT `COMPANY_ID`, `CATEGORY_ID`,`TITLE`,..."

Comment: should I use this method in my ENUM class?  how would I use the result set with a specific method

Comment: Yes that is for the enum Category. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

As I understood correctly you're storing the `category` in your `coupon` as an enum constant in your *code model*. While storing it to the database you're mapping it to an integer value with the methods provided by you.

The culprit is in the `Category.valueOf(resultSet.getString(3))` method/ part. The `Enum.valueOf` method is a default method on enums provided by `Java` and it's working with a `String` as a parameter - probably therefore you're also using `resultSet.getString(3)` instead of `resultSet.getInt(3)` which would have been more intuitive.

From the JavaDoc (which you can [find here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)) it says:

> ... The name must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum
> constant in this type. (Extraneous whitespace characters are not
> permitted.) ...

This means for to get the `valueOf` method working you need to call it exactly with one of the following values as its arguments: FOOD, ELECTRICITY, RESTAURANT, VACATION, HOTEL. Calling it with the int values like 1, 2, ... or 5 will lead to the `IllegalArgumentException` you face.

There a two solutions to fix the problem:

- Either change your database model to store the enum values/ constants as strings in the table by calling the `toString` method on the `category` value before the insert into the database (then your code reading the `coupons` from the database can stay unchanged).
- Or you need to provide your own custom implementation of the "`valueOf`" method - e.g. `findCategoryById` - which will work with integer values as its arguments. By writing your own `findCategoryById` method your code inserting the `coupons` into the database can remain unchanged.

To implement your own `findCategoryById` the signature of the method in the `Category` enum should look like:

```
public static Category findCategoryById(int index)
```

Then you can iterate through all available constants by `Category.values()` and compare the `cat` with the argument passed to the method and return the matching value based on it.

In case none matches you can simply return `null` or also throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. The latter one I'd personally prefer since it follows the "fail fast" approach and can avoid nasty and time consuming search for bugs.

---

**Note:** Enums in Java also have an auto generated/ auto assigned ordinal. You can simply request it by calling the `ordinal` method on a value of your enum. In your case the ordinals are matching the self assigned `cat` values, so that you could make use of them, instead of maintaining the `cat` attributes yourself.

When working with the ordinals it's worth mentioning that the order in which you specify your constants in the enum matters! When you change the order of the constants so the ordinals will. Therefore you also need to be careful when working with ordinals. Therefore you might prefer sticking with your current approach (which is not bad at all and widely used), since it avoids the ordering problems ordinals have.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed information it helped alot! Now I have a better understanding.